# Why does the Quran prescribe only lashing for fornicators but doesn't mention the stoning of adulterers?

Tags: quran, punishment, adultery

I am wondering why the Quran only states what the punishment is for unmarried fornicators, but does not mention the stoning of adulterers. This which seems to be a much more serious crime with a much more severe punishment.

Edit: Apparently I'm wrong that the Quran doesn't mention a punishment for adulterers and it would seem that the same punishment, lashing, applies to both unmarried and married individuals. So my question would be why is the stoning not mentioned in the Quran, but the lashing is?

Answer (score 1):

Quran and Sunnah are both sources of revelation. Asking why Allah gave a ruling in one source rather than another is a pointless question: It is like asking why the punishment of theft and banditry is in Surah Maidah and not Surah Nur where the punishment of slander and fornication are mentioned. There is no answer for it, Allah does as He wills.

Answer (score 0):

Who told you that the punishment of an adulterer or adulteress is not mentioned in the Quran?

> The punishment is mentioned in the Quran. The **zaniyah** and **zani**
>   found guilty of sexual intercourse - **lash each one of them with a
>   hundred lashes**, and do not be taken by pity for them in the religion
>   of Allah, if you should believe in Allah and the Last Day. And let a
>   group of the believers witness their punishment. (Surah 24:2)

Both the words "zaniyah" and "zani" came from the root word zina. Therefore, the adulterer is included in "zani" and adultress is included in "zaniyah".

Both the adulterer and adultress is to be lashed 100 times and it is proved by the above verse.

However, stoning the adulterer is a Sunnah and this mentioned in several Hadith.

I hope you got the answer.

Comment: Sure, so I guess this means that adulterers are lashed, **and** stoned to death. So my question is why is the stoning not mentioned in the Quran ( which is exclusive to adulterers).

Comment: @JohnDoe We dont ask why.. Allah wanted this. Thats it. And like my brother Zidan mentioned.. it's mentioned in Hadith, so it doesnt matter as we take our religion from Quran and Hadith. I mean we didnt just 'make it up'